# Xdebug doesn't terminate PHP script when debugging stops

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, xdebug-3

When I stop debugging, my PHP daemon script continues to run in the background.  How do I make xdebug automatically terminate/kill my PHP script when I stop debugging?

### My environment:

- PHP 8 (cli) with the xdebug extension.
- Visual Studio Code with the [PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension.

### Visual Studio Code (settings.json):

```
"launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PHP Debug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/xdebug.php",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log",
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug",
                "XDEBUG_TRIGGER": "true",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}",
            },
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        },
    ],
},
```

### Debugging test script (/path/to/xdebug.php):

```
<?php

sleep(15);
```

### Xdebug log (/tmp/xdebug.log):

```
[101075] Log opened at 2021-09-03 18:34:25.062284
[101075] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[101075] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[101075] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///path/to/xdebug.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.5" protocol_version="1.0" appid="101075" idekey="true"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[101075] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[101075] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[101075] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[101075] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[101075] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[101075] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[101075] [Step Debug] <- run -i 4

******** I stopped debugging at 18:34:30 ********

[101075] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="4" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[101075] Log closed at 2021-09-03 18:34:40.243542
```

Comment: Does VSCode send a "stop" or "detach" protocol command? To find out, make a log with the `xdebug.log` setting: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log and find out :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Detick.  Nothing in the logs (/tmp/xdebug.log) to indicate a stop/detach command received.  It finishes executing `sleep(15);` after I stop debugging then logs "Log closed".

Comment: There shouldn't be a `sleep(15)` in the log - can you show the last ~10 lines of the log?

Comment: Sorry, `sleep(15);` was the script I was testing xdebug with and is not included in the logs.  I've added `/tmp/xdebug.log` in the edited question above where I stopped debugging around 5 seconds before the `Log closed` message.

Comment: `[57177] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 5` — and you say "Nothing in the logs (/tmp/xdebug.log) to indicate a stop/detach command". It has `stop` in it. It is also replied to by Xdebug as `stopped`, and the next log line is `Log closed`. Looks like the script terminated just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted the log for when my script terminated naturally...I've updated the log now and included a comment for when I requested debugging to be stopped.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Debug extension maintainer here.

Due to Xdebug's "synchronous" nature, this isn't possible. You script is a good example.

Xdebug/DBGp can only process one request at time, and no new request can be received until the old has finished. Here the request is "run" and the response is `<response ... command="run" ... status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>` - received when the script stops.

So in between, you can't send any other commands like `stop`.

So in other words, you can only stop a scrip if it's in a paused state (i.e. breakpoint).

When PHP Debug receives the Disconnect Request form VS Code it tries to send a `stop` command - and if it fails to do so in 500ms (connection busy with a different request) it will simply disconnect from the process.

This would allow the PHP process to continue the code.

HOWEVER! If you started the script with the use of `program` field of `launch.json` the PHP Debug extension will also KILL the running process.

This isn't obvious here, but there might be some discrepancies in how the script is executed.